# FCM notifications are not received in android Oreo when battery is low

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am currently launching my video calling application on FCM message received event. It works fine. But in **Oreo** when the **battery is very low** I am not getting any FCM notifications. But Whatsapp works even in that scenario

I'm sending the following JSON:

```
{
    "to" : "XXXDecviceToken",
     "data" : {
         "callId" : "Call ID",
         "displayName" : "Abhilash", 
         "room" : "2000"
     }, 
     "time_to_live" : 0
}
```

Comment: Show how you are sending the push notification, the json

Comment: Have you set the priority to HIGH ?

Comment: `{
   "to" : "XXXDecviceToken",
   "data" : {
      "callId" : "Call ID",
      "displayName" : "Abhilash",
      "room" : "2000"
      }, 
   "time_to_live" : 0
 } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your JSON request:

```
{
    "to" : "XXXDecviceToken",
     "data" : {
         "callId" : "Call ID",
         "displayName" : "Abhilash", 
         "room" : "2000"
     }, 
     "time_to_live" : 0
}
```

There are two issues that can prevent your notification from being delivered when battery is low:

1. You don't specify a priority, so the default priority is "normal" for data messages:

> **By default**, notification messages are sent with high priority, and **data messages** are sent with **normal priority**. **Normal priority optimizes the client app's battery consumption** and should be used unless immediate delivery is required. For messages with normal priority, **the app may receive the message with unspecified delay**.

2. You specify "time_to_live" of 0, which means that if FCM fails to deliver the message immediately, it will never be delivered (since it's not kept in FCM storage).

So, combining "normal" priority with "time_to_live" of 0 is likely to prevent the message from being delivered when battery is low.

To try to overcome this issue, you can either set the priority to "high":

```
{
    "to" : "XXXDecviceToken",
     "data" : {
         "callId" : "Call ID",
         "displayName" : "Abhilash", 
         "room" : "2000"
     }, 
     "time_to_live" : 0,
     "priority" : "high"
}
```

or change "time_to_live" to a positive value (at least enough time to give the message a chance to be delivered after the battery is re-charged).